# Dates dont get change when adding time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I need to add `duration` to a time.

But what i have tried is this:

```
moment([year, month - 1, date, hour, minutes]).add('minutes', duration);
```

What it does is simply adds time which is fine but suppose i want to add `1:30 minutes` to `11:30 pm`, then it gives the result with the updated time only, not with the updated dates.

I need to know where i m doing wrong.?

Comment: Are you sure moment.js supports the incrementing of dates based on the duration parameter? And if it doesn't just handle it yourself.

Comment: Yes it does. i just found out.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my God. My mistake. It is changing date while adding `duration` to `time`.

Thanks :)